# Export a datatable with line-breaks in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I'm using `data.substr` to truncate long words in a DataTable. However, when I try to export the table using the button extension, the exported table contains truncated words represented by "..." instead of the entire words.

Is there a way to display the "..." within the Shiny app while ensuring that the entire table, without truncation, is exported to Excel?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dt = data.frame(x=c("blablablablablablablablablablablablal","blablablablablablablablablablablablal"),y=c(1,2))
  output$test <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(dt, rownames = TRUE,
                   extensions = 'Buttons',escape=FALSE,class = 'cell-border stripe',
                   selection = list( mode="single"),
                   option=list(dom = "Bt",buttons = list("copy", list(extend = "collection", buttons = c("csv", "excel"), text = "Download") ),
                               columnDefs = list(list(
                                 targets = c(0,1),
                                 render = JS(
                                   "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                   "return type === 'display' && data != null && data.length > 35 ?",
                                   "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 8) + '...</span>' : data;",
                                   "}")
                               ))
                   )
    )
                   
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

NB: I don't want to export the table using downloadHandler :-)

Thanks for your help

I've tried to use ellipsis plugins but i got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the *orthogonal data*:

```r
library(DT)

dt <- data.frame(
  x = c(
    "blablablablablablablablablablablablal",
    "blablablablablablablablablablablablal"
  ),
  y = c(1,2)
)

datatable(
  dt, rownames = TRUE,
  extensions = "Buttons", class = "cell-border stripe",
  selection = list(mode = "single"),
  options = list(
    dom = "Bt",
    buttons = list(
      "copy", 
      list(
        extend = "excel", 
        text = "Download",
        exportOptions = list(
          orthogonal = "export"
        )
      )
    ),
    columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = c(0, 1),
      render = JS(
        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
        "  if(type === 'export') {",
        "    return data;",
        "  }",
        "  return type === 'display' && data != null && data.length > 35 ?",
        "    '<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 8) + '...</span>' : data;",
        "}")
    ))
  )
)
```

This does not work for `extend = "collection"`.

Comment: Many thanks Stéphane, it works !